# Refresh $(document).ready in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a script that runs continuously on my page, and it detects if a new item has been submitted to my database, at which point it adds additional html to my page:

```
var count_cases = -1;

setInterval(function(){    
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "new_lead_alerts_process.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success : function(response){
            $.getJSON("new_lead_alerts_process.php", function(data) {
                if (count_cases != -1 && count_cases != data.count) {
                    //add new HTML element to page
                    $('#content').prepend("<div class=\"reportRow\"><div id=\"reportRowLeft\" style=\"width: 63px;\">"+dayOfMonth+"</div><div id=\"reportRowCenter\">"+timeSubmitted+"</div><div id=\"reportRowRight\" style=\"width: 126px;\"><div id=\"claimButton"+data.id+"\"><form action=\"\" method=\"post\" name=\""+data.id+"\"><input type=\"hidden\" id=\"lead_id"+data.id+"\" name=\"lead_id\" value=\""+data.id+"\" /><input type=\"hidden\" id=\"client_id"+data.id+"\" name=\"client_id\" value=\""+data.client_id+"\" /><input type=\"hidden\" id=\"user_id"+data.id+"\" name=\"user_id\" value=\"1\" /><input type=\"image\" name=\"submit\" class=\"claimButton\" onClick=\"expand('claimed"+data.id+"');collapse('claimButton"+data.id+"');\" src=\"images/claim.gif\" id=\""+data.id+"\" style=\"width: 126px; height: 29px; margin: 0; border: 0px; padding: 0; background: none;\"></form></div><img id=\"claimed"+data.id+"\" style=\"display: none;\" src=\"images/claimed.gif\" /></div><div id=\"clear\"></div></div>");
                }
            count_cases = data.count;
            });
        }
    });
},1000);
```

I have another script that submits an update to the database via AJAX when a user clicks a button in the newly created element. It looks like this:

```
//update db when lead is claimed
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".claimButton").click(function(){
        var element = $(this);
        var Id = element.attr("id");
        var client_id = $("#client_id"+Id).val();
        var user_id = $("#user_id"+Id).val();
        var lead_id = $("#lead_id"+Id).val();
        var dataString = 'client_id='+client_id+'&user_id='+user_id+'&lead_id='+lead_id;
        
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "new_lead_alerts_update.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false
        });
    return false;});
    });
```

My issue, is that the second AJAX submit doesn't appear to be working. I think this is due to the fact that the `$(document).ready` command only fires when the page first loads, and due to the fact that I'm updating the page content dynamically via AJAX, any new elements added to the page can't be submitted.

I've tried `.delegate` and `.live`, as opposed to `.ready` and neither appeared to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should delegate the event:`$(document).on('click', '.claimButton', function(){`

Comment: Why don't you do the stuff in the success callback of the AJAX function?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. However, I've tried all three of these approaches, and they don't appear to be the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the functionality from document.ready into a callback, and then do that every time you append a new element to the page from ajax like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ MakeClaim(); });

function MakeClaim(){
 $(".claimButton").click(function(){
    var element = $(this);
    var Id = element.attr("id");
    var client_id = $("#client_id"+Id).val();
    var user_id = $("#user_id"+Id).val();
    var lead_id = $("#lead_id"+Id).val();
    var dataString = 'client_id='+client_id+'&user_id='+user_id+'&lead_id='+lead_id;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "new_lead_alerts_update.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false
    });
 return false;});
}

success : function(response){
        $.getJSON("new_lead_alerts_process.php", function(data) {
            if (count_cases != -1 && count_cases != data.count) {
             //that huge string
             MakeClaim();
            }
            count_cases = data.count;
        });
}
```

**EDIT**

try changing this:

```
onClick=\"expand('claimed"+data.id+"');collapse('claimButton"+data.id+"');\"
```

to

```
onClick=\"expand('claimed"+data.id+"');collapse('claimButton"+data.id+"');return false;\"
```

Comment: This actually functions the same way as my original code. When I click the submit button on the dynamically inserted element it does a full refresh of the page, rather than submitting via AJAX.

Comment: @Jeremy - The page refreshes because any time a form is posted it refreshes the page. You can get around that by having a submit event on the form which returns false.

Comment: Hmm, that isn't true for the other forms on the page that weren't dynamically inserted. I'd assumed that the AJAX function suppressed submission of the form. I tried adding the following: `$('#form').submit(function(){
return false;
});` That didn't appear to work however.

Comment: @Jeremy - I wonder if that is because `return false` can have different meanings inside of jQuery closures.

Comment: I tried adding this to the form itself: `onsubmit="return false"` That successfully stopped the form from submitting, but it also stops the AJAX process from going through.

Comment: I also just tried your updated suggestion, and it has the same effect as my previous comment. It stops the form from submitting, but that also seems to disrupt the AJAX call.

Comment: @Jeremy - Okay, then try removing the onsubmit, and onclick return false parts, and change your input type to **button**.

Comment: I got rid of both the return false portions, and changed the input type to button, but got the same response. The form doesn't submit, but it also doesn't process the AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
function TryIt(getId)
{
        var element = $(getId);
        var Id = element.attr("id");
        var client_id = $("#client_id"+Id).val();
        var user_id = $("#user_id"+Id).val();
        var lead_id = $("#lead_id"+Id).val();
        var dataString = 'client_id='+client_id+'&user_id='+user_id+'&lead_id='+lead_id;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "new_lead_alerts_update.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false
        });

}
```

just use javascript onclick function in claimButton and call **TryIt()** function whenever you want.

Comment: That didn't work, sorry. It just refreshes the page and doesn't send any data through.

Comment: while trying to call TryIt() function, please call like TryIt(this);